# TimeAlarms stops working when using setSyncProvider(RTC.get) DS1307

Tags: arduino-nano, time, rtc

Been working on this project for some time now, like title states when I un-comment `setSyncProvider(RTC.get)` in the setup the program fails to get any of the `Alarm.timerOnce` to run.

I have been stuck for a while and couldn't find anything while just googling so I thought I might enlist the minds of stack.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>  // a basic DS1307 library that returns time as a time_t

//#define DS1307_I2C_ADDRESS 0x68 // the I2C address of Tiny RTC
//byte second, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month, year;

int curPin = 7, //  Current sense (middle terminal) connected to analog pin A7
  prePin = 6,     //  Pressure sense (green terminal) connected to analog pin A6
  ignPin = 7,     //  Igniter output pin D7
  solPin = 8,     //  Solenoid output pin D8
  genPin = 9,     //  Generator output pin D9
  tonePin = 11,   //  Tone output pin D11
  ligPin = 3,     //  Light sense pin A3
  intPin = 3,     //  Interupt pin D3 runs double bang

  runTime = 20,   //  minutes to run for

  state = 0;      //  state of operation

bool operate = false, // True if within operating time
   timeIsSet = false; // true if time till next opperation is set
double cur;     


void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ignPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(solPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(genPin, OUTPUT);   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //setSyncProvider(RTC.get);  //******************************************
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowMonday,7,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowTuesday,7,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowWednesday,7,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowThursday,7,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowFriday,7,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowSaturday,8,30,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(dowSunday,10,0,0,OnAlarm);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(20,0,0,OffAlarm);
  tone(tonePin, 31, 1000);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); // nothing connected to 0 so read sees noise

  OnAlarm();
}

void loop() {  
  if ((analogRead(ligPin) > 30) && operate == true)
  {
    if (timeIsSet == false)
    {
      tone(tonePin, 58, 500);
      int randm = random(27,36);
      Alarm.timerOnce(randm,operation);
      Serial.println(randm);
      timeIsSet = true;     
    }
  }
  digitalClockDisplay();
  Alarm.delay(1000); // wait one second between clock display
}

void operation(){
  tone(tonePin, 100, 1000);
  Alarm.timerOnce(12,after20m);
  digitalWrite(genPin, HIGH);
}

void after20m(){
  digitalWrite(genPin, LOW);
  Alarm.timerOnce(5,after5s);
  digitalWrite(solPin, HIGH);
  tone(tonePin, 494, 1000);
  timeIsSet = false;
}

void after5s(){
  tone(tonePin, 200, 1000);
  digitalWrite(solPin, LOW);
  Alarm.timerOnce(1,after1s);
}

void after1s()
{
  digitalWrite(ignPin, HIGH);
  Alarm.delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ignPin, LOW);
}

void OnAlarm() {
  operate = true;
}

void OffAlarm() {
  operate = false;
}

// Convert normal decimal numbers to binary coded decimal
byte decToBcd(byte val)
{
return ( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}
// Convert binary coded decimal to normal decimal numbers
byte bcdToDec(byte val)
{
return ( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

void digitalClockDisplay() {
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  printDigits(second());
  //Serial.print(operate);
  Serial.println();
}

void printDigits(int digits) {
  Serial.print(":");
  if (digits < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem existed in the TimeAlarms library,

```
Q: How many alarms can be created?
A: Up to six alarms can be scheduled.  
The number of alarms can be changed in the TimeAlarms header file (set by the constant 
dtNBR_ALARMS,
note that the RAM used equals dtNBR_ALARMS  * 11)
```

so how I fixed it was to edit `#define dtNBR_ALARMS 6  // max is 255` to `#define dtNBR_ALARMS 14   // max is 255` in the `TimeAlarms.h` file.

Comment: should this be an answer or add-on? you can edit the question

Comment: Looks like an answer to me. :)